# Move to previous entry with ArrayIterator?

Tags: php

```php
$list = new ArrayIterator(array('page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'));
echo $list->current(); // 'page1'
$list->next();
echo $list->current(); // 'page2'

// What I want to achieve
$list->previous();
echo $list->current(); // 'page1'
```

From there, how can I get last element `page1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `seek()` method and key index to move internal pointer to last element

```php
$list->seek($list->key() - 1);
```

Full example

```php
$list = new ArrayIterator(array('page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'));
echo $list->current(); // 'page1'
$list->next();
echo $list->current(); // 'page2'

$list->seek($list->key() - 1);
echo $list->current(); // 'page1'
```

Comment: Note this won't work on an associative array or an indexed array with holes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with an associative ArrayIterator, and this works both for simple and associative arrays, if you track the numeric position of the pointer as you cycle through the array ...

```
$list = new ArrayIterator(
    [
        'foo'  => 'page1',
        'bar'  => 'page2',
        'baz'  => 'page3',
        'qux'  => 'page4',
        'fred' => 'page5'
    ]
);
$numericIndex = -1;
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $numericIndex++;
    var_dump($list->current());
    if ($key === 'bar') {
        // Jump ahead to do stuff to the following elements
        $list->next();
        var_dump('Jumped ahead to: ' . $list->current());
        $list->next();
        var_dump('Jumped ahead to: ' . $list->current());

        // Rewind to original position to continue the loop 
        $list->seek($numericIndex);
    }
}
```

That outputs:

```
...:string 'page1' (length=5)
...:string 'page2' (length=5)
...:string 'Jumped ahead to: page3' (length=22)
...:string 'Jumped ahead to: page4' (length=22)
...:string 'page3' (length=5)
...:string 'page4' (length=5)
...:string 'page5' (length=5)
```